# Probability: there are $n$ rooms, and $m$ meetings, $m \leq n$, what's the probability of all meetings scheduled to a different room

Tags: probability

Quite new in stats... definitely not my strong area. I came across this probability question, and I am not sure how to do this!

The question goes:

> pretend that there's this meeting scheduling engine used by this
>   company and is not synced in real time, so when people schedule their
>   meetings online to book a room, there may be overlaps. let's say there
>   are $N$ rooms, and $M$ meetings, where $M \leq N$, what is the
>   probability that all meetings scheduled to a different room?

My thought was that, the first meeting doesnt matter, can be in any room; then the 2nd meeting has $\frac{1}{N-1}$ chance of being in a room. so for two rooms not colliding, the chance of them being in separate rooms is $\frac{1}{N-1}$. Right? I am not confident about this one neither...

Any hint/advice/guidance helps!

**update**
to clarify:

> 1) each room can only host up to one meeting
>   2) one meeting can only happen in one room

Comment: It depends on how the meetings are scheduled. Can two meetings be scheduled for the same room?

Comment: Hi @copper.hat, no, as stated in the title, all the meetings are scheduled to a different room. so no 2 meetings in a same room. hope that clarifies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are not talking about scheduling (for which time overlap would
an issue), but instead talking about just where the meeting takes place, then
there are $N^M$ possible assignments of meeting rooms. There are $\binom{N}{M}$
ways to choose $M$ different rooms for the meetings and $M!$ ways to assign the $M$ meetings to those rooms, so the probability is ${\binom{N}{M}M! \over N^M}$.

Comment: You need to multiply that by $M!$ to account for the ways the meetings can be permuted amongst the $M$ rooms chosen.

Comment: Thanks! I realized that but my train arrived before I had a chance to edit, stuck on phone for now.

Comment: If you like, I can make a quick edit; just let me know.

Comment: That would be much appreciated, otherwise I will get to in an hour and a bit. Thanks!

Comment: Done! (And now +1.)

Comment: @BrianM.Scott: Much appreciated!

Comment: can i please ask why multiply by M! ? i thought the (N M) will take care of assigning M meeting rooms to N total rooms already?

Comment: @alwaysaskingquestions: That was my original omission, which Brian fixed. There are $\binom{N}{M}$ ways of choosing $M$ rooms, but this does not take into account the $M!$ ways of assigning these rooms.

Comment: @copper.hat but (N M) already take into account when M rooms are ordered differently right? it calculates all the possible ways of choosing M rooms from N rooms total. i am not seeing how its different from M! ways of choosing the rooms? (thanks for being patient with me!)

Comment: @alwaysaskingquestions: No. At an extreme, there is exactly one way of choosing $N$ out of $N$ rooms, but there are $N!$ ways of assigning $N$ meetings to $N$ rooms.

Comment: @copper.hat ohhh i see. b/c (N M) does not count the orders of assigning the rooms. am i right? okay that make sense now!

Answer (score 3):

The total number of ways to distribute meetings to rooms is $N^M$, because for example the first meeting can take place in $N$ rooms, the second also in $N$ rooms, and so on.

Let's calculate the number of favorable situations. The first meeting has $N$ choices. The second has $N-1$ choices and so on. So the probability of all meetings are in different rooms is $$\frac{N(N-1)\cdots(N-M+1)}{N^M}$$

Comment: Hi msm, thanks so much for trying to help! i misinterpreted your answer. my apology. i do have a question regarding the N^M, how did you come up with that?

Comment: You want to assign rooms to meetings. For the first meeting there are $N$ options. For the second meeting there are also $N$ options. So for each of the $M$ meetings there are $N$ options, which means $N^M$ choices.

Comment: ah okay. that make sense! but why did you use (N-M+1) as the last element for the numerator? why +1?

Comment: The first term ($N$) is for the first meeting. $N-1$ for the second meeting, $N-2$ for the third meeting. So for the $M$'th meeting the corresponding term is $N-(M-1)=N-M+1$

Comment: so your answer is basically N!/(N^M)?

Comment: No. if you want to write it using factorial, it is $$\frac{N!/(N-M)!}{N^M}$$

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/51267/discussion-between-alwaysaskingquestions-and-msm).

Answer (score 2):

Same solution as the others with a slightly different perspective (somewhat in line with the reasoning you tried to provide).

Let $E_i$ be the event that room $i$ does not collide with rooms $1,2,3,...,i-1$.

As you noted the first room does not matter.

$$P(E_1)=1$$

For the second room, there are $N-1$ rooms we can pick out of the $N$ total taking into account the first room was chosen:

$$P(E_2|E_1)=\dfrac{N-1}{N}$$

Similarly,

$$P(E_3|E_2,E_1)=\dfrac{N-2}{N}$$

And the pattern continues in this fashion.

$$P(E_i|E_{i-1},E_{i-2},\cdots ,E_1) = \dfrac{N-i+1}{N}$$

You seek

$$P(E_1\cap E_2\cap \cdots\cap E_m) = P(E_1)P(E_2|E_1)P(E_3|E_2,E_1)\cdots P(E_m|E_{m-1},E_{m-2},\cdots,E_1)$$

$$=1\cdot \dfrac{N-1}{N}\cdot \dfrac{N-2}{N}\cdots \dfrac{N-m+1}{N}$$

Comment: ah, your answer totally make sense to me! thanks for going off my thought process, its easier for me to follow. can i ask why you use (N-M+1) as the last element for the numerator? why +1?

Comment: Notice for $E_2$ the numerator was not $N-2$ but $N-2+1$ or $N-1$. And the numerator for $E_3$ was $N-3+1$ or $N-2$. When we are choosing the $m^{th}$ room, there are only $m-1$ taken up so there are $N-(m-1)$ rooms left to choose from. $N-(m-1)=N-m+1$.

Comment: omg thank you so much! okay that totally make sense now. thank you very very much! i missed the pattern